# How to store sysdate value in a variable in triggers in oracle?

Tags: oracle, triggers, dynamic-sql

I have a trigger written as below:

```
create or replace
TRIGGER impt_downloadproc
before delete ON A
declare
storedate nvarchar2(80);
storetime nvarchar2(80);
sequel string(2000);
BEGIN
storedate := to_char(sysdate,'YYYYMMDD');
storetime :=  to_char(sysdate,'HH24MISS');
sequel:='create table B_'||storedate||'_'||storetime||' as select * from ipcsdd_download_process';
execute immediate sequel;
END;
```

What I am trying to do in my trigger is : Before someone/something deletes record(s) from A table, 
create a backup table B_yyyymmdd_hhmmss and backup the records to this table.

But I get error in line :storedate := to_char(sysdate,'YYYYMMDD');
I dont understand what is the problem.

Comment: I just get the message:ORA-06512: at "GOU.IMPT_DOWNLOADPROC", line 9
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'GOU.IMPT_DOWNLOADPROC'

Comment: I would expect a different error- you cannot commit in a trigger, you'll need to use an autonomous transaction (which is mostly not a good idea) [here is an example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1545b/1)

Comment: Then let me add it as an answer

Comment: This is a really bad idea. Apart from the problem of doing DDL from triggers, if there are multiple sessions all trying to delete at the same time, only one of them will succeed, and the rest will fail as they try to create tables with the same name. You'd probably be better off having a single "backup" table, and insert the deleted rows into that. Instead of having hundreds of little backup tables all over the place, each with a complete copy of the original table's contents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would expect a different error- you cannot commit in a trigger.
If you really want to then you'll need to use an autonomous transaction (which is mostly not a good idea)

So, your code should look something like this:

```
create or replace
TRIGGER impt_downloadproc
before delete ON A
declare
pragma   autonomous_transaction; -- see this line
storedate nvarchar2(80);
storetime nvarchar2(80);
sequel string(2000);
BEGIN
storedate := to_char(sysdate,'YYYYMMDD');
storetime :=  to_char(sysdate,'HH24MISS');
sequel:='create table B_'||storedate||'_'||storetime||' as select * from ipcsdd_download_process';
execute immediate sequel;
END;
```

[here is an example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1545b/1)

Comment: What can be the altenative? @ Jeffrey Kemp